# Creating a Django project on an existing empty git repository

Tags: django, git, pycharm

I'm pretty much new at programming using Mac, Django, Python and PyCharm. I wanted to create my first project and ran into the following problem:

For this project I want to use Python 3.7, so I installed it into my Mac using

```
pyenv install 3.7
```

And set a virtual environment with this line:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.16 python-3.7
```

Then, for the project I got an empty git repository and cloned it into my `/opt/` folder. I opened it with Pycharm and it appears to be empty, just as expected.

Then, I went to Files >> New Project, selected Django project and set the location of the project to the folder created during the clone, so the path is `/opt/my-first-project`. Then, I set the interpreter to be the environment previously created.

I get this warning on screen that says `Project name should only contain letters, numbers and underscores`. For the tests I've done, I guessed this refers to the name of the folder, `my-first-project` in this case. This is the name of the git repository, and since I'm not the owner of the repository I cannot change that name.

How should I create a new Django project inside this repository?

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to clone empty git repo? You can initiate your project git repository with `git init` command.

if you want to proceed with current condition, change your directory to

```
/opt/my-first-project
```

and activate python environment with `pyenv activate python-3.7`
and then install django framework on currently installed python virtual environment with `pip install django`

Create django project with valid characters such as : my_first_project
with

```
django-admin startproject my_first_project .
```

Open the project directory with pycharm, it works fine.

If you want initiate git here, you can do with `git init` command

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm cloning an empty repo because I'm not the owner of the repository and I need to upload the project there, so, if I'm not wrong, I can't do this with `git init`. Will give your solution a try and answer again. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I followed your steps and when I reach the part where I should execute `pyenv activate python-3.7` I get an error that says `Failed to activate virtualenv. Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly. Please restart current shell and try again`.

Comment: hat is the directory where is pyenv installed on your project?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Mac system so will do my best. Folder .pyenv is located at my user directory, so at `~/`. I'm also using iTerm as terminal with `zshrc` in case it helps understand something.